# when var_dump variable ...i m getting NULL is ouput

Tags: php, mysql

Database 
[image]

```
<?php
    if($cart_id != '')
    {
        $cartQ = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `cart`  WHERE id ='$cart_id'");
        $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartQ);
        $items = json_decode($result['items'],true);
        var_dump($items);
        $i = 1;
        $sub_total = 0;
        $item_count = 0;
    }
```

I'm getting value of var_dump as NULL

I should get the var_dump output as like this

```
array(1){[0]=> array(3) {['id']=> string(1)"8"["size"]=> string(5)"small"["quantity"]=>string(1)"1"}}
```

why it is returning NULL 
what is the problem in the code?

Comment: What do you get if you do `var_dump($result['items']);`? Most likely, it's not a valid json string.

Comment: Did you connect to you database. I see no code to do that?

Comment: You are doing no error checking! Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: @aynber i m getting NULL

Comment: WHat does the table `cart` look like, show us the schema

Comment: Please try and remove some of the unknowns for us. Remember we know only what you show us about your system/database/app

Comment: Well, that's an issue. If `var_dump($results);` returns null as well, then there are no rows returned. If you think there should be, check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) along the way, and echoing your query and pasting it directly into the database.

Comment: @RiggsFolly  https://i.stack.imgur.com/oocqM.png

Comment: Please dont make me have to format your question again. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Now show us what is in the `items` column for the row you are selecting in your query

Comment: To quote the [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) manual: **NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded** - I'm guessing that `$result['items']` isn't a valid JSON.